# not execute persistence on msaccess with PDO

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I´m trying to persist row in msaccess table but not do this with PHP pdo.

> Code

```
require '../db/pdoConect.php';
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of Agenda
 *
 * @author almir.oliveira
 */
class Agenda extends dbConnect {

    public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

function utf8_converter($array)
{
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
        if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
            $item = utf8_encode($item);
        }
    });
    return $array;
}

public function getAgendaByMedico($cod_medico){
    $db = $this->getdatabase(); 
    $sql = "Select * from agenda where CodigoMedico = $cod_medico and DataAgendada>= now()";

    $array = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll();
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"); 

    return  json_encode($this->utf8_converter($array));          
}

public function insertAgenda($agendaDados){

    $db = $this->getdatabase(); 
    //"Retorno               = '$agendaDados[Retorno]'              ,".
    //"StatusAgendamento     = '$agendaDados[StatusAgendamento]'    ,".
    //"NovoPaciente          = '$agendaDados[NovoPaciente]'         ,".
    //"Reagendamento         = '$agendaDados[Reagendamento]'        ,".
    $sql = "insert into Agendamento (  numeroProntuario ,                       
                                 FoneContato      ,    
                                 Convenio         ,    
                                 NomePaciente       )  ".

                "values  ".
                                    "(   '".$agendaDados['numeroProntuario']."' , ".                        
                "    '". $agendaDados['FoneContato'] ."'   ,  ".   
                "    '". $agendaDados['Convenio'] ."' ,   ".  
                "    '". $agendaDados['NomePaciente'] ."') ; ";

     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);       

     $sql="insert into Agendamento (  numeroProntuario ,                        
                                 FoneContato      ,    
                                 Convenio         ,    
                                 NomePaciente     ,   
                                                                     Retorno,
                                                                     NovoPaciente,
                                                                     Reagendamento,
                                 codigo_convenio_plano,
                                 CodigoMedico        )  values  ('PAR 08 1377 051',    'null'     ,    'PAR'        ,    'ABDO AZIZ NADER '    ,     false,     false ,     false,     null,    1      )";

     $result = $db->prepare($sql);  

     try{
         print_r($result); 
         $result->execute();
     }
     catch(Exception $e){
         print_r($e);
     }

}
```

}

> dbConnection

```
class dbConnect {

private $dsn="null";
private $username="postgres";
private $password="postgres";
protected $database;
public  function  __construct(){
    $this->conectar();
}

private function conectar(){

    $db_username = 'Admin'; //username
    $db_password = ''; //password

    //path to database file
    $database_path = "c:/sistemas/verea_db.accdb";

    //check file exist before we proceed
    if (!file_exists($database_path)) {
        die("Access database file not found !");
    }

    //create a new PDO object
    $this->database = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$database_path; Uid=$db_username; Pwd=$db_password");
    /*
    $this->database = new COM("ADODB.Connection"); 
   $this->database->Open(
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" .
    "Data Source=$database_path");
    */
}

public function getdatabase(){
    return $this->database;
}
```

};

there is no response error. Anybody knows what happened?

Comment: Have you figured out what line it's dying at?

Comment: Don't quote *null* if you intend to use the entity. Also, if no error, did you get undesired results? Any print output? Please be clear about the problem.